# SQL Server - Join two tables with not the same values

Tags: sql-server, join

I begin with SQL. I have two tables and I want to join them.

In table A, I have a column `Business` with two possible values: `Ins` or `Rea`.

In table B, I have a column `Outward` with two possible values: 1 or -1.

Knowing that 1 = "Ins" and -1 = "Rea", do you have a query which can help me to join these two tables?

Comment: WAMLeslie answer is correct, but I want to tell you, use correct field link, because only you (as developer) knows 1 = Ins and other associations. But is not the right way to build a normalized database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not much to go on since I don't know if you have any foreign keys or references in the tables.  But you could use a `JOIN` with a `CASE` if all you have is what's in the question above and there are no other values.

```
select *
from business b
join outward o
    on b.[value] = case when o.[value]=1 then 'Ins' 
                        when o.[value]=-1 then 'Rea'
                        end
```

Comment: Glad I could help.